# script src=massiv[] how to get

Tags: javascript, html

Мне нужно обратиться к серверу через script:

```
<script src=https://example.com/mass></script>
```

https://example.com/mass - по данной ссылке у нас находится массива вида: 1,2,3,4,5
то есть,когда я обращаюсь к серверу,он мне выдает данную строку 1,2,3,4,5
Как мне засунуть этот массив в script через src.

Чтобы получилась строка данного вида:

```
<script src=https://example.com/mass>alert(mass);</script>
```

Запрос должен быть обязательно с куками пользователя.

Comment: Ваш вариант не имеет шанса на жизнь. Используйте `fetch`.

Comment: Привет,теперь у меня новый вопрос))

Comment: <script>[["hey","no"]]</script> как вызвать этот массив без имени через alert?

Comment: Если я правильно вас понял, то можете просто вызывать toString() вашему массиву и заключить это в алерт: `alert([[]].toString())`. А вообще, непонятно, зачем это вам: если для отладки, то лучше console.log...